# Change of transit country

Tags: visas, transit

I have applied for Israel visa in December with Ethiopia as a country of transit.  Will the border security refuse me at the point of entry if I change my country of transit?

Comment: Do you mean Israeli border security? Or border security at the country of transit?

Comment: Change it to which country? Israel might refuse entry, depending on where you went just prior to your arrival.

Comment: Russia is my country of transit and Israel is my first country to travel

Comment: What a huge distance change in transit locations ha! Israel shouldn't have a problem, you may need a visa for Russia though.

Comment: I won't be leaving Sheremetyevo airport since the layover is 2 hrs. I would be requiring transit visa if I intend to leave the airport.

Comment: What border security? In Russia or in Israel?